# I have a number of questions about this (beginner) example code

Tags: ruby

Code below.

1) In the Ruby manual, it says that greater-than, less-than, etc. sign between classes checks for subordination, returning a boolean. But here we see

```
class RubyCSV < ActsAsCSV
end
```

I could understand if maybe this defined a new RubyCSV, subordinate to ActsAsCSV, but the Ruby manual says that the class on the left is actually the parent class! And from then on, the program seems to treat a RubyCSV as an ActsAsCSV. What's going on here?

2) 'File.new' creates a new, blank file, right? So why on the next line does the code start trying to read from it with 'gets'? Shouldn't there be nothing to get?

3) I'm told that if no parameter is given, Chomp will take off the default value. What is that default parameter?

4) I guess I just don't really understand how this functions as a CSV file. I don't see a two-dimensional data structure anywhere in here. @results would seem to include everything from all lines in a single one-dimensional array, *including* the stuff in @headers.

```
class ActsAsCSV
  def read
    file = File.new(self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt')
    @headers = file.gets.chomp.split(', ')

    file.each do |row|
      @result << row.chomp.split(', ')
    end
  end

  def headers
    @headers
  end

  def csv_contents
    @result
  end

  def initialize
    @result = []
    read
  end
end

class RubyCsv < ActsAsCSV
end

m = RubyCsv.new
puts m.headers.inspect
puts m.csv_contents().inspect
```

Comment: "but the Ruby manual says that the class on the left is actually the parent class" - I don't think so. You probably misread it.

Comment: "'File.new' creates a new, blank file, right?" - no. It opens a file. Depending on the flags you pass, the file may be auto-created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: "So 'file.gets.chomp' just makes an unmodified copy of file.gets, right?" - no. `chomp`'s parameter will have the default value in this case.

Comment: "@results would seem to include everything from all lines in a single one-dimensional array, including the stuff in @headers." - no. `@headers` will be a flat array, but `@result` will be an array of arrays. I assume you're observing this and are asking "how on earth does this happen here"?

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please ask multiple questions. [so] is for questions that have a single, canonical, objectively verifiable, correct answer. This requires a single, focused, well-specified question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm limited to one post every 90 minutes. It would be impractical to spend six hours just to post these four elementary questions.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What is that default value for Chomp?

Comment: @AidanofVT: it's in the documentation.

Comment: Crafting a good Stack Overflow question takes a lot longer than 90 minutes anyway, so that limit should not be a problem. Also, when you post good, on-topic, high-quality questions, you will very quickly gain reputation, and that limit will be lifted. This particular question in its current form, however, will very likely gain you downvotes, which will *increase* the limitations.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Let my introduce myself. I am a student. I am currently working my way through chapter 1 of a Ruby textbook. Thus far, every time I have clicked 'I need help with a homework problem,' I have been very pleased with the helpful responses. I was led to believe that stackoverflow was welcoming to novices with simple questions. However, if I am mistaken, and these sorts of beginner questions are beneath stackoverflow's experts, I would be very appreciative if you could recommend another forum which is more appropriate.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question, taking account of the earlier comments. That should stop the downvotes and conceivably result in a few being retracted. Your question will remain on SO forever, so you have an obligation to make it clear for members who read it tomorrow, next month and in 2078.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's begin by creating a csv file named `"actsascsv.txt"`.

```
IO.write('actsascsv.txt', "Name, Age, IQ\nWilber, 33, 86\nBianca, 18, 143\nBluto, 83, 55")
  #=> 58 (characters written)
```

Let's look at that file.

```
puts IO.read('actsascsv.csv')
Name, Age, IQ
Wilber, 33, 86
Bianca, 18, 143
Bluto, 83, 55
```

Now consider each the instance methods of the class `ActsAsCSV`, where

```
acts = ActsAsCSV.new
  #=> #<ActsAsCSV:0x000058857127ac28 @result=[["Wilber", "33", "86"],
  #     ["Bianca", "18", "143"], ["Bluto", "83", "55"]], @headers=["Name", "Age", "IQ"]>
```

```
def headers
  @headers
end

def csv_contents
  @result
end
```

```
acts.headers
  #=> ["Name", "Age", "IQ"] 
acts.csv_contents
  #=> [["Wilber", "33", "86"], ["Bianca", "18", "143"], ["Bluto", "83", "55"]]
```

These two (instance) methods are called *getters*, as they return the values of instance variables. Here the instance variables are `@headers` and `@result`. The first of these methods is typical, where the name of the method is the same as the name of the instance variable, without the *at* character, `"@"`. It's curious that the second was not named `result` or the instance variables was not `@csv_contents`.

The first of these methods is normally created using the method [Module#attr_reader](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) by writing:

```
attr_reader :headers
```

I've covered these two methods first because *getters* and *setters* are customarily written at the beginning of a class definition, using one of the three `attr_...` methods<sup>1</sup>.

```
def initialize
  @result = []
  read
end
```

`initialize` (a private instance method) is invoked when the method `new` is called on the class. Here it initializes the instance variable `@result` to an empty array and calls the method `read`. `initialize` is customarily the first instance method appearing in the class definition.

```
def read
  file = File.new(self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt')
  @headers = file.gets.chomp.split(', ')

  file.each do |row|
    @result << row.chomp.split(', ')
  end
end
```

This method<sup>2,3</sup> initially executes:

```
file = File.new(self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt')
```

The class method [File::new](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/File.html#method-c-new) takes a single argument, the file name (including the path). Here that is<sup>4</sup>:

```
a = self
  #=> acts 
b = a.class
  #=> ActsAsCSV 
c = b.to_s
  #=> "ActsAsCSV" 
d = c.downcase
  #=> "actsascsv" 
e = d + '.txt'
  #=> "actsascsv.txt" 
file = File.new(e)
  #=> #<File:actsascsv.txt>
```

Next,

```
f = file.gets
  #=> "Name, Age, IQ\n" 
g = f.chomp
  #=> "Name, Age, IQ" 
@headers = g.split(', ')
  #=> ["Name", "Age", "IQ"]
```

See [IO#gets](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-i-gets), [String#chomp](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-chomp) and [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split). Then,

```
file.each do |row|
  @result << row.chomp.split(', ')
end
  #=> [["Wilber", "33", "86"], ["Bianca", "18", "143"], ["Bluto", "83", "55"]]
acts.csv_contents
  #=> [["Wilber", "33", "86"], ["Bianca", "18", "143"], ["Bluto", "83", "55"]]
```

See [IO#each](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-i-each)<sup>5</sup>.

```
class RubyCsv < ActsAsCSV
end

RubyCsv.superclass
  #= ActsAsCSV
```

This merely creates a subclass of `ActsAsCSV` which inherits the latter's constants and methods.

```
m = RubyCsv.new
  #=> Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - rubycsv.txt)
```

As indicated, an exception is raised because there is no file `rubycsv.txt`.

The conventional way of reading and writing CSV files with Ruby is to use methods of the class [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

<sup>1 See also [Module#attr_writer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer) and [Module#attr_accessor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor).</sup>

<sup>2 Assuming this method is called only from other of the class' instance methods (here `initialize`), is generally would be defined as a private method, so it could not be called from outside the class.</sup>

<sup>3 It is customary, but not required, for CSV file names to have the suffix `"csv"` (i.e., `'actsascsv.csv'`). Moreover, when writing CSV files it is best to avoid adding spaces on either side of the field separators (commas unless otherwise specified).</sup>

<sup>4 The explicit receiver `self` is used here. When there is no explicit receiver within instance methods the receiver defaults to `self`, so it generally is not necessary to include `self.`. `class.to_s.downcase` raises an exception, however, as Ruby interprets `class` as the keyword to create a class. This is one of a handful of situations where `self.` is required within an instance method.</sup>

<sup>5 `IO` class methods are often written with `File` as the receiver. That is permissible because `File` is a subclass of `IO` and therefore inherits the latter's methods.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. Just what I needed.